# Why is my code resulting in runtime error?

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error

I am given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. I have to write a code that adds the two numbers and return it as a linked list(in the reverse order as well).

I have written the following code. It works fine as long as the last digit is not 9. It looks like it is a memory allocation problem but I can't figure out what.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong and how to fix it ?

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* struct ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode *next;
*     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
* };
*/

void adder(int &value, bool &carry) {
   if(carry) value++;
   if (value > 9) {
      value = value%10;
      carry = true;
   }else carry = false;
}

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode* prev = NULL;
        bool carry = false;
        ListNode* curr1 = l1;
        ListNode* curr2 = l2;
        ListNode* worker = NULL;

        while(curr1 != NULL && curr2 != NULL){
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        }

        if(curr1 != NULL) worker = l1;
        else worker = l2;

        ListNode* result = worker;
        curr1 = l1;
        curr2 = l2;

        while(curr1 != NULL && curr2 != NULL) {
            int value = curr1->val + curr2->val ;
            adder(value, carry);
            worker->val = value;
            //cout<<curr1->val<<endl;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
            prev = worker ;
            worker = worker->next;
        }

        while(worker != NULL && carry) {
            int value = worker->val;
            adder(value, carry);
            worker->val = value;
            prev = worker;
            worker = worker->next;
        }

        ListNode last(1);

        //the following line results in runtime error
        if(carry) {
            prev->next = &last;
        }

        return result; 

    }
};
```

Comment: The proper tool to use to figure this out is your debugger. At the very last you could pinpoint which line causes the error

Comment: Taking the address of a local variable is a recipe for disaster (&last). It will be invalid outside of the scope in which it is declared

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to add a pointer to a local variable that is going away when the subroutine exits to the end of a linked list?

Comment: looks like leetcode ...

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @UnholySheep That's my TM :P

Comment: @UnholySheep: I already figured out which line is causing the error and i pointed out that line as well. My question was why and not what. What i really want to know was why is that address allocation causing a problem. I know that prev at that point is pointing to NULL. What I want to know is why is reassignment to a non NULL value a problem here but intiatlizing prev to a NULL value and then changing it later in the code is not.

Comment: @Walter: Yep, it is. The point of posting it here was to figure out what I was doing wrong rather than completely replacing my code with someone else's .

Comment: The bug is here:  `prev->next = &last;`

Comment: @infixed: Can you elaborate more on that. Thank you.

Comment: The memory for last no longer is valid when `addTwoNumbers()` exits. However it is a pointer in your list. You must not use a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: @drescherjm : Ah !!! Thank you so much. If I were to fix this, is there any way other than using a global variable ?

Comment: You are creating a local ListNode with the `ListNode last(1);`  then adding that to the linked list to mark the end.  But it's allocated on the stack, so when you exit the routine, you do not own that part of the stack anymore.  So you link list is tied to memory you have no right to use.  You might be able to say `static ListNode last(1);`, but you'd have to worry about it when freeing your linked list nodes later  
`

Comment: Actually, the `static` idea would be bad if you were linking other stuff to that list later and started to mess with `last.next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two obvious errors. **First**, there is no guarantee, as far as I can see at least, that `prev` in

```
prev->next = &last;
```

is non-NULL. This is an error in the logic of your algorithm. **Second**, you're adding a local object `last` to the linked list. Instead, you should allocate a new `ListNode` using `new`, e.g.

```
assert(prev);       // must not be NULL
prev->next = new ListNode(1);
```